# Setting up Apache web server with Vagrant

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant

**UPDATE**: So I'm not sure what was wrong but I completely reinstalled Vagrant, Virtual Box, Ubuntu, and Apache (probably overdid it by reinstalling everything). Everything works correctly now.

---

I am trying to install Apache web server in Ubuntu 14.04. I got the image from Vagrant's atlas site. The image is called: `ubuntu/trusty64`.

I can get Ubuntu initialized and running perfectly fine. I install Apache with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

However, back on my local machine (Windows 10), I try to visit the ip specified in the `Vagrantfile` file:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.7"
```

Nothing comes up. Shouldn't I see the welcome page for Apache as seen here: [Apache Ubuntu Default Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCp3H.png).

All I get is "Unable to connect". Am I not understanding how Vagrant works? How can I use the Ubuntu machine as a web server?

Answer (score 3):

In your vagrant file, you should create a port for your VM to receive http requests on port 80 and define a port to respond to the request which is any available port.

If your VM is running on the same machine as your browser, then you are automatically have to send requests to your local ip address which is port 127.0.0.1 or use localhost.

So instead of putting in

config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.7"

in your vagrantfile, I suggest putting in something like this:

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

The above line tells your virtual machine to receive http requests on port 80 and respond on port 8080.

So you can then navigate to http://localhost:8080 to see your page.